# Minimising jerk by publishing faster than subscribing

Tags: python

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there a way I could publish a node at a different rate of subscribing?

I do intend to have a python script instercept /cmd_vel and publish it 5 times faster in incrementally.

For eg:

```
pub = rospy.Publisher("/cmd_vel", Twist)
rospy.SUbscriber("/pre_cmd_vel")
i = 1
rate = rospy.Rate(10)
while linear.change < 5:
    rate = rospy.Rate(50)    
    p.linear.x = i
    pub.publish(p)
    i = i + 1
    rate.sleep()
rate = rospy.Rate(10)`
```

Would something like that work? SInce jerking is caused by acceleration, breaking a command for a sudden jump in velocity into smaller blocks would give less jerk?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/280585/minimising-jerk-by-publishing-faster-than-subscribing/) by [Alsing](https://answers.ros.org/users/28489/alsing/) on ROS Answers with karma: 27 on 2018-01-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Would [wiki/yocs_velocity_smoother](http://wiki.ros.org/yocs_velocity_smoother) not do what you want?

As to your question: of course you can 'publish faster than you subscribe' (more accurate would be: publish faster than the rate at which messages are incoming). Just use a timer to control the publication rate.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-01-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Alsing](https://answers.ros.org/users/28489/alsing/) on 2018-01-23**:
Thanks for the recommendation!

I'll take a look at it. HOwever, is my implementation correct?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-01-24**:
Well, no:

- `Rate` inside `while`
- no callback for your subscriber

and some other things.

I would really recommend using the velocity smoother. If you must create something yourself: use a timer, not a while loop.

And I don't understand the `p.linear.x = i` line.

**Comment by [Alsing](https://answers.ros.org/users/28489/alsing/) on 2018-01-24**:
@gvdhoorn The crux of the code would be having rate inside while. So while [condition], rate is different. But I looked at the timer and probably will go with that route. Or yocs_velocity_smoother. Thanks alot!

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-01-24**:
I don't think `Rate` works like you think it does: it's a convenience object, that keeps track of time for you between calls to `sleep()`. It doesn't affect scheduling of your `while` loop or something. Creating multiple `Rate` instances at different lines will not do anything special.